# Java Eclipse how to view active listeners in debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, listener

How can I see what listeners are active whilst debugging?

I can see where I "setListener" as I step through - but as there is never a callback I am wondering if the listener is actually still alive.

Answer (score 0):

You can point a breakpoint inside a listener code, so you can see when it has been invoked. Does it help you?

Comment: Your listener should be still alive unless you invoke method 'removeListener' (method name is convention). If you put breakpoint inside listener code and it has not been executed - that means that your listeners are not being notified, by underlying code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark a breakpoint at the listener variable you want to follow
2. When the breakpoint is hit, see the Variables Pane (Show -> View -> Variables) and find in there the name of the listener variable you are following
3. Right click in the variable and choose "Open Actual Type"

This open the code that your listener variable points at the next debug step.

=)

Comment: After several weeks I realized that what it just need to do is press F5 (IDE Eclipse)... lol...